# Making the fireworks launch when the button is pushed

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-listener, buttonclick

I have been trying to figure out how to make the fireworks launch when the button is clicked. I can get the audio to play just fine, but not the fireworks. I am not sure if I should add an `EventListener` in a different area or if I need to try a different method.

I've tried adding an `EventListener`, adding click to the existing `EventListner`, and adding a class to the launcher `CSS` and the button.

```
function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
       audio.play();
      };

// Fireworks
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var num_launchers = 12;
  var num_flares = 20;
  var flare_colours = ['#f22613', '#ffffff', '#22a7f0', '#00b5cc', '#f3f1ef', '#d91e18'];
  var cssIdx = document.styleSheets.length - 1;

  function myRandom(from, to)
  {
    return from + Math.floor(Math.random() * (to-from));
  }

  var keyframes_template = "from { left: LEFTFROM%; top: 380px; width: 6px; height: 12px; }\n"
      + "33% { left: LEFTTOP%; top: TOPTOPpx; width: 0; height: 0; }\n"
      + " to { left: LEFTEND%; top: BOTBOTpx; width: 0; height: 0; }";

  for(var i=0; i < num_launchers; i++) {
    leftfrom = myRandom(15, 85);
    lefttop = myRandom(30, 70);
    toptop = myRandom(20, 200);
    leftend = lefttop + (lefttop-leftfrom)/2;
    botbot = toptop + 100;

    csscode = keyframes_template;
    csscode = csscode.replace(/LEFTFROM/, leftfrom);
    csscode = csscode.replace(/LEFTTOP/, lefttop);
    csscode = csscode.replace(/TOPTOP/, toptop);
    csscode = csscode.replace(/LEFTEND/, leftend);
    csscode = csscode.replace(/BOTBOT/, botbot);

    try {
      csscode2 = "@-webkit-keyframes flight_" + i + " {\n" + csscode + "\n}";
      document.styleSheets[cssIdx].insertRule(csscode2, 0);
    } catch(e) { }

    try { 
      csscode2 = "@-moz-keyframes flight_" + i + " {\n" + csscode + "\n}";
      document.styleSheets[cssIdx].insertRule(csscode2, 0);
    } catch(e) { }
  }

  for(var i=0; i < num_launchers; i++) {
    var rand = myRandom(0, flare_colours.length - 1);
    var rand_colour = flare_colours[rand];
    var launch_delay = myRandom(0,100) / 10;

    csscode = ".launcher:nth-child(" + num_launchers + "n+" + i + ") {\n"
      + "  -webkit-animation-name: flight_" + i + ";\n"
      + "  -webkit-animation-delay: " + launch_delay + "s;\n"
      + "  -moz-animation-name: flight_" + i + ";\n"
      + "  -moz-animation-delay: " + launch_delay + "s;\n"
      + "}";
    document.styleSheets[cssIdx].insertRule(csscode, 0);

    csscode = ".launcher:nth-child(" + num_launchers + "n+" + i + ") div {"
      + "  border-color: " + rand_colour + ";\n"
      + "  -webkit-animation-delay: " + launch_delay + "s;\n"
      + "  -moz-animation-delay: " + launch_delay + "s;\n"
      + "}";
    document.styleSheets[cssIdx].insertRule(csscode, 0);
  }

  for(var i=0; i < num_flares; i++) {
    csscode = ".launcher div:nth-child(" + num_flares + "n+" + i + ") {\n"
    + "  -webkit-transform: rotate(" + (i * 360/num_flares) + "deg);\n"
    + "  -moz-transform: rotate(" + (i * 360/num_flares) + "deg);\n"
    + "}";
    document.styleSheets[cssIdx].insertRule(csscode, 0);
  }

  for(var i=0; i < num_launchers; i++) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
    newdiv.className = "launcher";
    for(var j=0; j < num_flares; j++) {
      newdiv.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    }
    document.getElementById("stage").appendChild(newdiv);
  }
}, false);
```

I expect the music and fireworks to start when the button is clicked. If you need the `CSS` or `HTML`, I can add that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**call firework inside this block inside**

> document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",
>   function(){**place firework**});

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){

  // Fireworks
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var num_launchers = 12;
  var num_flares = 20;
  var flare_colours = ['#f22613', '#ffffff', '#22a7f0', '#00b5cc', '#f3f1ef', '#d91e18'];
  var cssIdx = document.styleSheets.length - 1;

  function myRandom(from, to)
  {
    return from + Math.floor(Math.random() * (to-from));
  }

  var keyframes_template = "from { left: LEFTFROM%; top: 380px; width: 6px; height: 12px; }\n"
      + "33% { left: LEFTTOP%; top: TOPTOPpx; width: 0; height: 0; }\n"
      + " to { left: LEFTEND%; top: BOTBOTpx; width: 0; height: 0; }";

  for(var i=0; i < num_launchers; i++) {
    leftfrom = myRandom(15, 85);
    lefttop = myRandom(30, 70);
    toptop = myRandom(20, 200);
    leftend = lefttop + (lefttop-leftfrom)/2;
    botbot = toptop + 100;

    csscode = keyframes_template;
    csscode = csscode.replace(/LEFTFROM/, leftfrom);
    csscode = csscode.replace(/LEFTTOP/, lefttop);
    csscode = csscode.replace(/TOPTOP/, toptop);
    csscode = csscode.replace(/LEFTEND/, leftend);
    csscode = csscode.replace(/BOTBOT/, botbot);

    try {
      csscode2 = "@-webkit-keyframes flight_" + i + " {\n" + csscode + "\n}";
      document.styleSheets[cssIdx].insertRule(csscode2, 0);
    } catch(e) { }

    try { 
      csscode2 = "@-moz-keyframes flight_" + i + " {\n" + csscode + "\n}";
      document.styleSheets[cssIdx].insertRule(csscode2, 0);
    } catch(e) { }
  }

  for(var i=0; i < num_launchers; i++) {
    var rand = myRandom(0, flare_colours.length - 1);
    var rand_colour = flare_colours[rand];
    var launch_delay = myRandom(0,100) / 10;

    csscode = ".launcher:nth-child(" + num_launchers + "n+" + i + ") {\n"
      + "  -webkit-animation-name: flight_" + i + ";\n"
      + "  -webkit-animation-delay: " + launch_delay + "s;\n"
      + "  -moz-animation-name: flight_" + i + ";\n"
      + "  -moz-animation-delay: " + launch_delay + "s;\n"
      + "}";
    document.styleSheets[cssIdx].insertRule(csscode, 0);

    csscode = ".launcher:nth-child(" + num_launchers + "n+" + i + ") div {"
      + "  border-color: " + rand_colour + ";\n"
      + "  -webkit-animation-delay: " + launch_delay + "s;\n"
      + "  -moz-animation-delay: " + launch_delay + "s;\n"
      + "}";
    document.styleSheets[cssIdx].insertRule(csscode, 0);
  }

  for(var i=0; i < num_flares; i++) {
    csscode = ".launcher div:nth-child(" + num_flares + "n+" + i + ") {\n"
    + "  -webkit-transform: rotate(" + (i * 360/num_flares) + "deg);\n"
    + "  -moz-transform: rotate(" + (i * 360/num_flares) + "deg);\n"
    + "}";
    document.styleSheets[cssIdx].insertRule(csscode, 0);
  }

  for(var i=0; i < num_launchers; i++) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
    newdiv.className = "launcher";
    for(var j=0; j < num_flares; j++) {
      newdiv.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    }
    document.getElementById("stage").appendChild(newdiv);
  }
}, false);

});
```

Comment: The Codepen works fine. It just doesn't work with my app.

Comment: I am not trying to completely change my code. I am just trying to get what I currently have to work once the button is pushed.